# Zapier StoreClient undefined

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'm trying to store state between calls similar to the documentation here: https://zapier.com/apps/code/help#code-examples

However, I try to run the code from a Zap, I get:

> StoreClient is not defined

The documentation states that I shouldn't have to require anything to use StoreClient:  "There is no need to require it - it comes pre-imported in your Code environment."

I'm on the latest version of zapier-platform-core (8.3.0).
I'm using the exact code from the example linked above.

```
 const count = await store.get('some counter')
 const newCount = (count || 0) + 1;
 await store.set('some counter', count);
 return {count: newCount};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question!

This is a little bit unclear based on the docs - `StoreClient` is only available in the Code app (aka `Code by Zapier`). If you're using `zapier-platform-core`, you're creating a cli app, which is a vanilla node.js environment. If you want to interact with `Storage by Zapier` from within a cli app, you can use the docs on the site: https://store.zapier.com. Namely:

```
{
  "how does it work?": {
    "always provide either `?secret=12345` or `X-Secret: 12345`": "",
    "GET /api/secret": [
      "will return a random secret for you to use if you need one."
    ],
    "GET /api/records": [
      "will return a full object of all values stored by default.",
      "you can also specify only the keys you want via the",
      "querystring like`?key=color&key=age`."
    ],
    "POST /api/records": [
      "provide a body with a json object with keys/values you want",
      "to store like `{\"color\": \"blue\", \"age\": 29}`."
    ],
    "DELETE /api/records": ["completely clear all the records in this account"],
    "PATCH /api/records": [
      "A data with a particular schema needs to be received.",
      "The schema specifies which action to do and with what parameters.",
      "For example {\"action\": \"increment_by\", \"data\": {\"key\": \"<key_name>\", \"amount\": 1}} to increment the value specified by \"key\"."
    ]
  }
}
```

Requests to those endpoints can be made using the standard `z.request`, which is well-documented here: https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#making-http-requests